# How does Ruby enumerator terminate iteration?

Tags: ruby, enumerable, enumerator, take

Friends, please I need help with this explanation: In the Ruby code below, what condition termites the loop do? It's supposed to be an infinite loop, but, how does it terminate?

```
# Ruby code
fib = Enumerator.new do |y|
  a = b = 1
  loop do
    y << a
    a, b = b, a + b
  end
end

p fib.take(10) # => [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```

Your contributions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: As an aside, in Ruby v2.7 the Ruby monks have bestowed upon us the method [Enumerator::produce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-c-produce), which simplifies the creation of some enumerators, including one that generates Fibonacci numbers: `enum = Enumerator.produce([0, 1]) {|n1, n2| [n2, n2+n1]}`. For example, the first 8 Fibonacci numbers are given by `arr = enum.take(8) #=> [[0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 5], [5, 8], [8, 13], [13, 21]]` followed by  `arr.map(&:first) #=> [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]`.

Answer (score 4):

(Source: https://rossta.net/blog/infinite-sequences-in-ruby.html)

The way you have implemented the function `fib` allows it to be "lazy." What this means, is that Ruby will not try to calculate the values in `fib` until it absolutely has to.

The `take` method on the last line is key here.

```
p fib.take(10)
```

Basically, Ruby says "I'm going to evaluate the first 10 values of `fib` and pretend the rest do not exist, as I don't **have to** use them yet."

In other words, while it is true that the `fib` function is potentially infinite, you only asked for the first 10 values, so you only got the first 10 values.

If you tried something like this:

```
p fib.to_a
```

Your program would get stuck. Why? Because the `to_a` (to array) method wants to try get **all** the values of fib, not just a few of them. Obviously, you cannot get **all** the values of an infinite list.

For more information:

https://medium.com/background-thread/what-is-lazy-evaluation-programming-word-of-the-day-8a6f4410053f

https://github.com/juinc/tilap/issues/9

--- EDIT: ---

Technical correction: As Cary Swoveland pointed out, it would be more technically correct to say that `fib` is an algorithm/machine that produces values on demand.

Answer (score 1):

An enumerator is like a [Pez<sup>®</sup> dispenser](https://us.pez.com/pages/history), which ejects a peppermint candy each time the top of the dispenser is pressed. An enumerator version of the dispenser would not hold a supply of candies, but would manufacture the candies one at a time, on demand, possibly being capable of producing an infinite number of them.

One type of an enumerator is tied to an underlying collection of objects. Here are two that are tied to an array.

```
enum = [1,2,3].each #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:each> 

enum.next #=> 1 
enum.next #=> 2 
enum.next #=> 3 
enum.next #=> StopIteration (iteration reached an end)
```

```
enum = [1,2,3].cycle #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:cycle> 

enum.next #=> 1 
enum.next #=> 2 
enum.next #=> 3 
enum.next #=> 1 
enum.next #=> 2 
... ad infinitum

enum.first(8)
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

In the first example only a finite number of objects are generated by the enumerator before a `StopIteration` exception is raised. In the second example an arbitrary number of objects can be generated, but only on demand. `first`, for example, instructs `enum` `8` times to generate and pass to itself one object. `enum` is not *lazy*; it is all-to-eager to comply, but will not manufacture and dispense an  object until it is instructed to do so.

The other type of enumerator generates objects according to a set of rules that it was born with, rules that are not tied to an underlying object. Those enumerators are generally capable of generating an infinite number of objects. The enumerator that generates Fibonacci numbers is an example of that type of enumerator. It is not a loop that does not terminate; it is a machine that is capable of producing any number of objects, but only one at a time, on demand.